# citing from zotero for workflow in emacs/AUCTex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, emacs, auctex, zotero

I am trying to develop a workflow as I begin writing my dissertation (in the social sciences). I am using emcas as my LaTeX editor, Zotero as my citation manager, and Linux Mint as OS. I had a question of a simple workflow to allow me to add citations from Zotero. I know one way is to export a bib file from Zotero and use that in my .tex file. But the problem with this workflow is that it requires exporting a bib file each time I make an addition to citations. Is there better emacs+zotero+biblatex integration?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18848/35864). I don't think, however, that you can get away with not exporting to a `.bib` file if you added a new reference. There is no way LaTeX/`biblatex`/Biber are able to know about it, if it is not in the `.bib` file. (See also [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31869/35864))

Comment: I was not thinking there would be a way to avoid exporting the .bib file, but was hoping there might be a zotero add-on that might modify the .bib file as citations were added as one made citations while writing in emacs.

Comment: In the last link someone advertises their zetoro add-on that does auto-exporting of a `.bib` file, maybe that is worth looking at. I'm not sure if there is a way for zotero to know you cited using emacs and it might be a good idea to export the `.bib` if something new came along.

Comment: That's correct, I don't think there's a great way for Zotero to keep track of which items you've cited in a particular document, so full export is probably best. 
I'm pretty sure this: https://github.com/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex is by far the most complete Zotero-->bib(la)tex solution, allowing for both a lot of automation (like pull export, which won't slow down Zotero) and a lot of customization. Very responsive dev, too.

Comment: I have tried the workflow yet, but from the links above one option seems to be to use both the zotero auto-export extension and the better-bib(la)tex extension to automatically update my entire database as a .bib file when changes are made. -- Is there a way for auto-completion of citations in emacs linked through the .bib file?

Comment: I'm not sure about auto-completion in Emacs, but these tow links seem to suggest something is possible [Setting up RefTeX Tab completion in emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9682592) and [Autocomplete Pandoc-style citations from a Bibtex file in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13607156), [RefTeX Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/reftex.html) and [Autocompleting \cite{} with emacs + auctex gives “cite: no such database entry”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3063189). What you need to keep in mind then is that this only works if the `.bib` file is up to date.

Comment: Do you have any inkling of what you would like an answer to this question to look like? Could you maybe answer the question yourself?

Answer (score 11):

[Better BibTeX for Zotero](https://zotplus.github.io/better-bibtex/) allows for automated export to BibTeX/BibLaTeX (a.o.). It's set-and-forget; you export a collection to a file, tick "Keep updated", and Bob's your proverbial uncle. Any changes you make to that collection or its entries will cause a background update of the bib file.

You can have multiple of such exports set up -- BBT implements heavy caching, so most of the time you won't even notice that its busy (except that one user with a crazy 22k entries in a single collection -- that takes a little under a minute).

Full disclosure: I am the author of BBT.

Answer (score 1):

Zotelo is an emacs package to synchronize your collections from emacs.

https://github.com/vspinu/zotelo