# How to get LyX and zotero together?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, zotero

I am using the latest versions of LyX and zotero.  What I want is pretty simple: to import citations in LyX from zotero --- and to import new papers into zotero and have zotero auto-update the .bib file I'm using in LyX.

How can this be done?

The workflow I'm currently using is very awkward and silly:  Every single time I add something to zotero, I have to export all my zotero items into a the same bib file, and from there LyX takes on.  I'm certain this can be done otherwise zotero is terrible for a paying service.

In other words, how can zotero have a single bib file that's updated once a new zotero item is included?  I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, but I couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: The answer to this  question might be helpful: [How to quickly transfer selected references from Zotero to BibDesk?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/31869)

Answer (score 4):

Try installing [Better BibTeX](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/).

With this extension you can export your library to BibTeX and set it to automatically update when you edit your database.

To my knowledge, what you ask can be done only with this extension.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, please show us with an example on how to do it and please refrain from providing link-only answers to the questions. Because, these link will tend to die over-time.

Comment: The link I  provided is an extension that does exactly what is asked in the question. To my knowledge this is the only way to do this. This is why I just provided the link.

Comment: With BBT installed, if you check the checkbox "Keep updated" when you export a bib(la)tex file, any new changes in your zotero library will be re-exported to that file automatically. LyX will pick up the changes when you recompile your document there.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have found the [lyz plugin](https://github.com/willsALMANJ/lyz) for zotero.

It lets you, ***from zotero but not from LyX***, to select an item, and then press a button wich will include that item's citation in your LyX document.

It works, and I am *truly grateful* to its author.  But this should be coming from the zotero guys, because it's not the best workflow.  When you are writing a document and want to cite something, you do not want to start another program (zotero), then on zotero send some command that will alter the file on your editor.

The optimal interoperability would be to not care about zotero --- at all. This is optimal because the user is concentrated in writing, and from within the document quickly press a button and choose what to cite. I write this in hopes that the zotero people will eventually:

- Let users know, from within zotero, the available plugins, instead of having to browse the webforums for hints.
- To make it interoperable, such that zotero becomes `invisible' to the user at the document writing stage.

Comment: Did you check the answer I linked in my comment? It seems to do things more seamlessly.  But I don't use either LyX or Zotero, so I can't check it.

Comment: Thank you, Alan.  I'm checking it now, and it seems that this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430894/33832) makes for a normal workflow.